# Running procedure without trigger

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, insert

How can I run the stored procedure when there is an insert operation in SQL Server (without trigger), that is, when data is entered into the table?

```
CREATE TRIGGER Mail_Send
ON [Oral_Overprint_2].[dbo].[table]
AFTER INSERT
AS   
BEGIN
    EXEC Mail_Table_Procedure 
END
```

Comment: Canonically, a trigger would be how you would do it. Why is that not an option for you?

Comment: I want to send sql dbmail with trigger. Normally I can do this with trigger, but there is a query in my mail and this query is not working.

My query is preparing a table and sending this table by mail. But when I add it in trigger, empty mail comes.

So my query in trigger is not working.

How can I send an e-mail other than trigger when I register to the table?

Comment: That sounds less like a trigger problem and more like a problem with your stored procedure. I'd look more into that. If you need help debugging it, either add the relevant details to this question or ask a new one.